# How to make hash-tags with meteorjs and iron:router?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, iron-router, hashtag

Im trying to make hash-tags support with iron:router.
Now I have data of posts, each post has an array of tags, which renders as a list of links.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
  {{#each tags}}
    <li>
      <a class="tag" href="{{pathFor 'postsTag'}}">{{this}}</a>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

But I cannot understand how to get the value of a tag on click and to render posts according to this specific hash-tag.

I can get the value of a tag by Session on click

```
Template.post.events({
  "click .tag": function(e) {
     Session.set('tag',this.toString());
     return false;
   }
});
```

But i cannot make dynamic router on it.I tried something like that

```
Router.route('/posts/:tag',{
  name: 'postsTag',
  data: function() {
    return Posts.find({tags:{$in: value_of_tag }});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If `tags` is a simple array of strings, you can query this field to match a particular value using this syntax :

```
Posts.find({
  tags: "value"
});
```

`$in` is used when you want to search for documents having a particular field value among a set of values defined in an array.

```
Posts.find({
  tags: {
    $in: ["value1","value2","value3"]
  }
});
```

This query would return posts having a tags array containing at least one of the specified value, which would be useful if you want to filter posts using multiple tag values.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in

If you want to define a route displaying only posts having a particular tag value, use this controller :

```
Router.route("/posts/:tag", {
  name: "postList",
  waitOn:function(){
    return Meteor.subscribe("postsByTag",this.params.tag);
  },
  data: function() {
    return Posts.find({
      tags:this.params.tag
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok, but how to make a router?

Comment: You need to define a `RouteController` that returns posts having a tag value corresponding to the route URL tag value parameter.